# HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error when using custom ObjectMapper

Tags: spring, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I'm using Springboot v2.4.3, and jackson v.2.12.2.

I made a custom ObjectMapper to mask sensitive fields in a dto.
My initial thoughts when implementing code was to apply this feature only during serialization, but it seems to be affecting deserialization and can't seem to find out why.

My configurations are:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration<T> implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
        converters.add(marshallingMessageConverter());
        converters.add(createXstreamXmlHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    }

}
```

based on this, I made a custom ObjectMapper, and registered the configurations like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new MaskAnnotationIntrospector());
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

my intention was to apply masking logic only to fields that were annotated with @MaskJson.

```
public class MaskAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public Object findSerializer(Annotated a) {

        MaskJson maskJsonAnnotation = a.getAnnotation(MaskJson.class);

        if (maskJsonAnnotation != null) {
            return MaskingSerializer.class;
        }
        return super.findSerializer(a);
    }
}
```

```
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JsonSerialize(using = MaskingSerializer.class)
public @interface MaskJson {
    MaskingTypeEnum type();
}
```

```
public class MaskingSerializer extends StdSerializer<String> implements ContextualSerializer {

    private MaskingTypeEnum maskingType;

    protected MaskingSerializer(MaskingTypeEnum maskingType) {
        super(String.class);
        this.maskingType = maskingType;
    }

    public MaskingSerializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) {

        if (property != null) {
            MaskJson maskJson = property.getAnnotation(MaskJson.class);

            if (maskJson != null) {
                MaskingTypeEnum maskingTypeValue = maskJson.type();
                return new MaskingSerializer(maskingTypeValue);
            }
        }

        return this;
    }


    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            gen.writeString(DisplayUtils.getMaskingData(value, maskingType));
    }

}
```

the masking logic works as intended, but i'm getting a

> [HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized field
> "fieldName"]

exception when calling an api that does not utilize `@MaskJson` annotation.

the api looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test/all", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public ResponseDTO getAll(@RequestBody SearchRequest request) throws ParseException {

}
```

the request dto that's making this issue is this:

```
@Getter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class SearchRequest extends CommonSearch implements SearchParam {
}

@Getter
@ToString
@MemberIdentifierValid
public class CommonSearch {
    private String memNo;
    private String info;

    @JsonProperty("fieldName") private String fieldname;
}
```

my custom configuration JacksonConfig seems to be affecting all fields that are using the annotation `@JsonProperty`. If the annotation is used in the format of `@JsonProperty("fieldNameLikeThis")`, some how the fields are read in the form of "fieldnamelikethis".

Why is my custom serializer affecting the existing HttpMessageConverter?

Comment: Have you tried to add setter To the commonSearch Object?

Comment: @Jens just tried, but am getting the same error.

Comment: I would suggest to ditch the `WebMvcConfigurer` and the `JacksonConfig` and instead write a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` which adds the introspector to the regular Spring Boot created `ObjectMapper` (or rather the factory that builds it).

Comment: Can you please share the json from the request?